# Can XML schemas enforce dependencies between values?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Let's say we have this simple XML document:

```
 <A>
     <B value ="x">
     <C value ="y">
 </A>
```

Is it somehow possible to limit the "value" (in DTD and/or Schema)  that as soon as I choose something for x within the XML data, the value y turns into the same.

For example:
I write `<B value ="water">` so `<C value ="">` turns   self-acting into `<C value ="water">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML schemas (DTDs, XSDs, Schematron, etc) define ***validity*** of XML documents.  They do not implement relationships where the changing of one value would result in the change of another value.

So, you might use an XML schema to say that the `value` attributes between `B` and `C` elements must be equal, but that's different than causing them to be equal.  Validation would report whether your constraint is met or not -- a boolean result, along with some diagnostic messages describing constraint violations.  To cause changes to an XML document based on other changes elsewhere in the document, you'd need to program that.

Final note:  DTD and XSD 1.0 cannot enforce such a validity constraint that spans across elements; XSD 1.1 or Schematron could, however, using XPath-based assertions.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know - perfectly explained.
Thank you for your help.